# combine Text box and dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a UI such a way that either user can enter his own text or use the dropdown to select the text.

I was able to achieve to some extent. I need to bring the look first element same as that of Select Location dropdown.

https://jsfiddle.net/techjerk2013/vwpsxhaL/3/

```
 <div id="div3">
        <div id="div4" class="row" style="padding-left: 50px">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-6">
                <div id="div5" class="dropdown">
                    <input id="Text1" name="" type="text" style="width: 95px;" />
                    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="Button3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btnCategory" id="ul3" runat="server">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal3"></asp:Literal>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-6">
                <div id="div6" class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="Button4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        Select Location
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btnCategory" id="ul4" runat="server">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal4"></asp:Literal>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [Bootstraps Input Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns)

Comment: I think your are looking to create a combobox. Have a look at this bootstrap plugin : https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

Comment: @jumojer I do not have any option to enter a new text other than selecting from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Would the jquery chosen dropdown be something that you are looking for? You can add the class to a asp dropdown and use the type ahead ability to select items that around bound to it. Or did I misunderstand the question?

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: In chosen I cannot enter any new text other than selecting

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the datalist tag in html.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

It's import to note that this does not work in safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist